# Autodesk APS Forge Can I get family instances insertion points (location) and rotation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, derivative, forge, aps

is it posible with Forge Derivative API to get instances location(insertion points) and rotation info from revit file that is uploaded in bucket and converted?

I am geting data and metadata with Derivative API but not seeing there is Location, rotation info for individual objects

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the things you saw in Revit API are unavailable with Model Derivative API. The Model Derivative API is a common-facing service that extracts partial metadata from the source model file, and geometries data will be simplified into meshes.

If you want Revit API perspective data, I would advise you to use Design Automation API for Revit instead. You can write addin using Revit API to extract instances' location(insertion points) and rotation info.

- https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/about_this_tutorial/